# Why is the button switch not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a button switch case. The button is pressed the images are added to subview when the button is clicked again it will remove it from the superview if it is clicked again it will add them again, etc.

```
        var buttonState: Int = 0;

        func addfriend(sender: UIButton){
        switch(buttonState){
            case 0:
                self.view.addSubview(cameramethod)
                self.view.addSubview(searchmethod)
                self.view.addSubview(nearbymethod)
                buttonState = 1;
         break;

            case 1:
                cameramethod.removeFromSuperview()
                searchmethod.removeFromSuperview()
                nearbymethod.removeFromSuperview()

               default: break;
        }





}
```

Comment: Do you use switch or button?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

```
func addfriend(sender: UIButton){
        switch(buttonState){
            case 0:
                self.view.addSubview(cameramethod)
                self.view.addSubview(searchmethod)
                self.view.addSubview(nearbymethod)
                buttonState = 1;
            break;

            case 1:
                cameramethod.removeFromSuperview()
                searchmethod.removeFromSuperview()
                nearbymethod.removeFromSuperview()
                buttonState = 0;
            break;

            default: break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a boolean type instead of an Integer to save the button state:

```
var buttonDisplay = false

func addfriend(sender: UIButton){
    // toggle your button state when pressed
    buttonDisplay = !buttonDisplay
    // check if true
    if buttonDisplay {
        // case positive add your subviews
        view.addSubview(cameramethod)
        view.addSubview(searchmethod)
        view.addSubview(nearbymethod)
    else {
        // otherwise remove them
        cameramethod.removeFromSuperview()
        searchmethod.removeFromSuperview()
        nearbymethod.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, play with tag value of button.

```
  func addfriend(sender: UIButton){
        switch(sender.tag){
            case 0:
                self.view.addSubview(cameramethod)
                self.view.addSubview(searchmethod)
                self.view.addSubview(nearbymethod)
                sender.tag = 1;
         break;

            case 1:
                cameramethod.removeFromSuperview()
                searchmethod.removeFromSuperview()
                nearbymethod.removeFromSuperview()
                sender.tag = 0;
               default: break;
        }
```